# What should be the timing to capture screenshots as images and then convert the images to video file using ffmpeg?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, video, ffmpeg

I have a timer tick event where i take screenshots every 10ms

```
        int count = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sc.CaptureScreen());
            bmp.Save(@"D:\SavedScreenshots\screenshot" + count + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            bmp.Dispose();
            count ++;
        }
```

Then i i'm using ffmpeg command line in command prompt window to create a video file from all the images:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 2 -i screenshot%d.bmp -c:v libx264 -r 30  -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Every bitmap file on hard disk it's size is 7.91 MB
The details: 1920x 1080 and Bit depth 32

The problem is when making the ffmpeg command line with -framerate 2 then when i play the video file in windows media player it's very very slow.
When i saet the framerate to 10 then it's too fast. 
When i set the framerate to 4 i'm getting error in yellow say too large.

But maybe the problem is that i'm taking a screenshot every 10ms ? Maybe i should take a screenshot every 1000ms ? And then what should i change in the ffmpeg command line ?

I want it to be like a regular video file speed. Not too fast and not too slow.
What i'm capturing in the screenshot is my desktop screen and later i want to upload and show it to some support help in a forum.

Comment: regular video speed like in youtube is about 24fps or 30fps. It means 24 or 30 bitmaps in 1 second. Your timer must be 1000/24 or 1000/30 milisecond. I think in ffmpeg, -framerate 1/24 or 1/30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly capture, using FFmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

(Press Ctrl-C or q to stop).

You can resize the captured file,

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 out-small.mp4
```

---

If you want to continue using C#, use a timer interval of 1000/24 ms and

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i screenshot%d.bmp -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```